# Compute the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{(s^2+3)}{(s^2+2s+2)^2}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I tried a few things, like completing the square in the denominator and going from there, but nothing really gets me anywhere or matches the answer that has been posted.

Comment: Maybe you could show your attempts? They could be mostly correct, and wouldn't it be better if someone just points out a small error in your own solution rather than provides you a full one?

Comment: Change $s$ to $s-1$.